# ways to call Func delegate inside Func delegate

Tags: delegates, func, c#-6.0

I am new Func delegate in my existing code there is one function . can someone explain How to work with Func delegate?

```
public static ListColumn SetBColorFunction(this ListColumn column, Func<object, Func<object>, Color> colorFunction)
{
    column.BackColorFunction = colorFunction;
    return column;
}
```

Now i want to know what are the ways to call this above function?

Comment: Hi there rocky, your question does not make a lot of sence. You wnat to know how you can call a function in C#?

Comment: Sorry Sir , May i am not clear enough . As you can see there is Func delegate used in function .  So I just know if i want to call this SetBcolorFunction  then what i need to pass.

Comment: Can anyone please answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method description:

1. `SetBColorFunction` is an extension method so you need not pass the first parameter.
2. It takes a method which takes a delegate and a `Color` as parameters and returns an `object`. The delegate can take a method which returns an `object` and doesn't take any argument.

So with this understanding try the following solutions.

**Solution 1:**

```
Color Callback(object o, Func<object> func)
{
    object obj = func();
    return new Color();
}

void Consumer()
{
    ListColumn listColumn = new ListColumn();
    listColumn.SetBColorFunction(Callback)
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Using lambda.

```
void Consumer()
{
    ListColumn listColumn = new ListColumn();
    listColumn.SetBColorFunction((obj, func) => {// Do your work and return object})
}
```